# Laravel error 500 in Ajax query

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have a code:

```
function addProductInCart() {
    var product = 1;

    var token  = $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content');
    $.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token }});



    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add_to_cart",

        data: {"product": product, '_token':token},
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    })
}
```

I have a route:

```
Route::post('/add_to_cart', 'AjaxController@addProduct');
```

I have error 500.

I can not understand a reason of error.

Comment: Error 500 is server error. Look at `storage/logs`/laravel.log` or apache/nginx error log for some information.

Comment: Error is url is wrong here. You need to add URL like this. `url:"{{URL('/add_to_cart')}}"`

Comment: POST http://shop/public/%7B%7BURL('/add_to_cart')%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery-3.0.0.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-3.0.0.min.js:4
addProductInCart @ handler.js:25
onclick @ VM1770 selectProduct:105

Comment: Adding the full URL is fine. You don't need to use the `URL()` function, especially if the code lives in a js file instead of a blade template. But definitely look in `storage/logs` to find out why the server is complaining.

Comment: It's working if i place my php code in route.php. But external file does not work

Comment: Have you looked at the information found in `/storage/logs`? Any error thrown will be there. A 500 error is a generic server error, and covers just about anything that can go wrong with a PHP script.

Comment: File has so much text information. I don't understand what I need.

Comment: Delete it, and then try to access your page again. Then just the information you need will be there. If you can't understand what it means, post the information here, starting from the last timestamp.

Comment: I deleted all text and tried get access on page. But log file is empty

Comment: I think your route it's wrong. Try: Route::post('/add_to_cart', 'AjaxController@addProductInCart'); your function on the controller is addProductInCart() and not addProduct();

Comment: This is a php code. addProduct it's function in php file. 
function addProduct(){
    $count = session("count");
    $product = 1;
    session(["count" => $count + $product]);
    $json = json_encode(session("count"));
    echo $json;
}

Answer (score 0):

I found issue. It's so stupid reason of error. I placed my php method outside class. And was error, because class AjaxController did not have method "addProduct". Thanks all for the help. Sorry what I am so stupid)